# What is the UINavigationBar's UIFont?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

How do I programmatically get the font, color, shadow, etc. of a UINavigationBar's title?  I am using Xcode and Cocoa touch.

Comment: To be clear, your asking how to obtain these values, not set them right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary * attributes = navigationBar.titleTextAttributes;
UIFont * font = [attributes objectForKey:UITextAttributeFont];
...more pairs exist in attributes...
```

Comment: This really doesn't help.  The variables return nothing.

Comment: @blake305 apparently, they do *if they have been set*.